# vb.net Document Generation, Handling Greater Than & Less Than Symbols in Word

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, ms-word, word-automation

We are using TinyMCE editor to store Rich Text in a MS SQL database.

When using "<" & ">" symbols, TinyMCE converts these into the HTML escaped characters  &lt ; and &gt ; For Example: `<p>&lt;This is some test information then sometime I use this&gt;</p>`

We are trying to export these symbols in a Microsoft Word document using document automation however the symbols do not appear in the document.

```
    Function PreFormatHTML(ByVal html As String) As String

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(html) Then Return html

        html = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(html)

        Return html

    End Function

Dim SumRng As Word.Range = objWordDoc.Bookmarks.Item("bSummary").Range

SumRng.Text = PreFormatHTML(GeneralComponent.CheckReadNull(SqlReader.Item("Summary")))
```

This also doesn't work. I'm using Word 2013 and TinyMCE text editor.

Any suggestions?

Comment: eek... Ask yourself a question... which characters does HTML use to identify and wrap objects... The &gt; and %lt; are standard escape sequence characters that allow you to still use < & > in your text.

Comment: Yes, I understand why it's not appearing. It thinks it's a blank HTML Tag. The issue is, when I use &gt or &lt Word isn't picking it up. It's just displaying the &gt or &lt. Instead of "<" ">"

Comment: then you need to be more specific.. where is the text coming from... where are you putting it..

Comment: I have updated the question, hopefully that's more clear. All the information is there...

Comment: `Function PreFormatHTML(ByVal html As String) As String` @Bugs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the full `html` I can only make an assumption however what I would suggest is use [WebUtility.HtmlDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388354(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Converts a string that has been HTML-encoded for HTTP transmission into a decoded string.

This is how you would use it:

```
html = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(html)
```

With `Word` this is how I have tested:

```
Dim s As String = "&lt;this is some text and I'm wondering what to do&gt;"

Dim wrd As New Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document = wrd.Documents.Add()
Dim para As Word.Paragraph = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add()

para.Range.Text = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(s)
```

This is what the text looks like in my `Document`:

[image]

Edited as per OP's comment:

```
Dim s As String = "<p>&lt;This is some test information then sometime I use this&gt;</p>"

Dim wrd As New Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document = wrd.Documents.Add()
Dim para As Word.Paragraph = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add()

para.Range.Text = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(s)
```

This code produces the following output in my `Document`:

[image]

Edited as per OP's update to question:

I have created a document called `test.docx` and added a bookmark called `bSummary`. I have done this in an attempt to replicate the OP's code.

```
Dim s As String = "<p>&lt;This is some test information then sometime I use this&gt;</p>"

Dim wrd As New Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document = wrd.Documents.Open("C:\test.docx")

Dim SumRng As Word.Range = doc.Bookmarks.Item("bSummary").Range
SumRng.Text = PreFormatHTML(s)
```

<s>The output is the same as above. This leads me to think that whatever is passed into `PreFormatHTML` is not what you think it is. Is `GeneralComponent.CheckReadNull(SqlReader.Item("Summary")))` passing into `PreFormatHTML` the following string; `<p>&lt;This is some test information then sometime I use this&gt;</p>`?</s>

OP has confirmed the HTML is returned from `PrrFormatHTML` as expected. The issues seems to be linked to the `Document`. It may be to do with the with version of Word Interop that the OP is using. I'm using `Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library` whilst the OP is using `Microsoft Word 15.0 Object Library`.

Comment: It works only for > For example try this: `<p>&lt;This is some test information then sometime I use this&gt;</p>` Then nothing appears. I will update my question with more details.

Comment: @DaleLawrence what do you expect that to look like in your document? Like this: `<p><This is some test information then sometime I use this></p>`?

Comment: Yes, I'm just looking to be able to export both < and > in the same sentence, but the < isn't appearing at all. If they are both used the text in between and the symbols don't appear.

Comment: The html I posted above is the input to PreFormatHTML.  What is being returned is `<p><This is rubbish data></p>`

Comment: I have copied your code so mines is identical now, but it's still not working. What version of Word Interop are you using to do your word automation?

Comment: @DaleLawrence `Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library`

Comment: My version is 15.0 this could be the issue, I will try updating this. Thanks for you help.

Comment: @DaleLawrence that would surprise me but if it does then come back and confirm. It would be well worth noting that's the issue.